# Unable to include a header-only library

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following project structure:

```
utils 
 include 
  image_utils.h
 CMakelists.txt
 package.xml
graph
 src
  graph.cpp
 CMakelists.txt
 package.xml
```

I am trying to use `image_utils.h` in `graph.cpp`.

The `CMakelists` inside utils looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(utils)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp 
)
include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
)
```

And in the `CMakelists` inside graph i call `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp utils)`.

My error message is:

```
  Project 'graph' tried to find library 'utils'.  The library is neither
  a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project 'utils'?
  Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing its code is
  included?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412299/unable-to-include-a-header-only-library/) by [milano](https://answers.ros.org/users/137155/milano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have this:

> ```
> catkin_package(
> ```

```
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp 
)
```

Note the `LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}` specifically.

This makes Catkin export a library target called `${PROJECT_NAME}` (in this case that would be equal to `utils`) to all your dependents.

This causes CMake, when parsing `utils/CMakeLists.txt` to expect a `utils` library target to exist (ie: be exported) by your `graph` project.

Since `utils` is header-only (according to you), there is no such `utils` library, hence the error message.

If you remove the `LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}`, things should start working (or at least: you shouldn't get *that* error any more).

PS: there are quite a few duplicates of this question here on ROS Answers. I've not looked them up this time, but please try to search before posting. Use Google, and append `site:answers.ros.org` to your query.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [milano](https://answers.ros.org/users/137155/milano/) on 2023-02-09**:
Now it works, thank you!
Sorry, I searched for similar issues, but none of the solutions I found worked.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-02-09**:
No need to apologise.